# Sorting Custom Linked List in Java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have created my own linked list implementation that stores a first name and a last name. Now I am trying to sort the list of names alphabetically by the last name, which I am having trouble doing. I have read about possibly using collections.sort but I am not sure how I can modify my class so I can use collections.sort or if that is even a good way to go about it or not. Below is what I have done so far. If anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated. What I want to accomplish is that when I print it will print Joe Rogers, Bill Thomas, Greg West, which would mean it was sorted by last name.

Edit: Thanks everyone for your quick responses, I really appreciate it.

```
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LinkedList l = new LinkedList();

    l.insert("Greg", "West");
    l.insert("Joe", "Rogers");
    l.insert("Bill", "Thomas");

    l.print();

    Collections.sort(l) // I am unable to get this to work


}

public static class myLink {
public myLink next;
public String first;
public String last;

public myLink(String first, String last)
{
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}

public void print()
{
    System.out.printf("%s %s\n",first,last);
}
}

public static class LinkedList {
private myLink linkedList;

public LinkedList() 
{
    linkedList = null;
}

public void insert(String first, String last)
{
    myLink li = new myLink(first, last);
    li.next = linkedList;
    linkedList = li;
}

public void print()
{
    myLink c = linkedList;
    while(c != null)
    {
        c.print();
        c = c.next;
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: But the code has no sorting code? What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: "I am not sure how I can modify my class so I can use collections.sort" - why not?  What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I am thinking of using collections.sort(l) , but that doesn't work with my implementation. I was just wondering how I could accomplish that?

Comment: why don;t use build in LinkedList? why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I have tried using Java's linked list, but the add method only lets you use a single string and I want to use a first and last name. So then when I use collections.sort() on the list it doesn't work right

Comment: No the list allows you to add a single object. You could have a class that holds 1000 fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried using Java's linked list, but the add method only lets you use a single string

No, you can add your class as well. Simply implements `Comparable` interface add put your logic in overridden `compareTo()` method.

Use `Collections.sort()` to sort the list.

sample code:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();

```
    l.add(new MyLink("Greg", "West"));
    l.add(new MyLink("Joe", "Rogers"));
    l.add(new MyLink("Bill", "Thomas"));

    Collections.sort(l);
    for(MyLink link:l){
        link.print();
    }
}

public static class MyLink implements Comparable<MyLink>{
    public MyLink next;
    public String first;
    public String last;

    public MyLink(String first, String last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.printf("%s %s\n", first, last);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyLink o) {
        int result = this.last.compareTo(o.last);
        if(result==0){
            result = this.first.compareTo(o.first);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

output:

```
Joe Rogers
Bill Thomas
Greg West
```

---

You can achieve it without implementing `Comparable` interface.

Simply use [Collections.sort(List,Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method.

sample code:

```
Collections.sort(l,new Comparator<MyLink>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(MyLink o1, MyLink o2) {
        int result = o1.last.compareTo(o2.last);
        if(result==0){
            result=o1.first.compareTo(o2.first);
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

Note:

- Never use build in class's name for your class that might sometime create confusion
- Respect Java Naming convention.

Comment: @Gregwest85 I doubt it, this solution works only because the nodes were added to Java's own `LinkedList` class - in other words: this is not using your linked list implementation, but Java's. The links inside each node are pointing to wrong values. Perhaps you shouldn't call your class `MyLink`, instead call it `Person` and remove the `next` attribute because you're not using it anyway.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez please have a look at the OP comments. OP has tried to use buildin LinkedList but OP is facing some issue to add other than String. If LinkedList is already there then there is no need to create a custom class that behave in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

LinkedList will work for you. You only need your `Person`   class, and a customised `Comparator` as in below example.

```
public class Person {
    String first;
    String last;
    public Person(String f, String l) {
        this.first = f;
        this.last = l;
    }
}

public class LinkExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Person> pList = new LinkedList<Person>();
        pList.add(new Person("AFirst","ZLast"));
        pList.add(new Person("BFirst","BLast"));
        Collections.sort(pList, new Comparator<Person>() { 
           public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
            return p1.last.compareTo(p2.last);
           }
        });
        System.out.println(pList.pollFirst().last);
        System.out.println(pList.pollFirst().last);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your class `myLink` implement `Comparable` interface. Then override `compareTo()` method as per your requirement.Then you can sort using `Collections.sort(collection);`

For more info read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

Also take care of Java naming conventions. `myLink` should be `MyLink` and so  on...

This will sort the Collection of `myLink` . But if you want to sort your custom `LinkedList` class I would suggest create a method `sort()` in `class LinkedList`. In this method create a List of all your `myLink` instances (You have reference to the head). Then call `Collections.sort()` here and return Sorted Collection.

Comment: I don't think so that will fix the issue in custom linked list class.

Comment: Yes agreed it will not help sort the custom LL class. Edited the answer for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a Person bean object which:

- contains the firstname and surname, and
- implements Comparable to sort on the surname

Then all you have to do is put all your Person objects in an ArrayList, and use Collections.sort() to get them in the right order.

Comment: Have a look at custom linkedlist class